# Continuous Integration - how to add a bugfix to a live build?

Tags: integration, live, continuous

We are in the process of implementing continuous integration in our organisation, and one of the questions that arose is how to fix a bug in the live build.

1. Do we simply add the fix into the continuous integration branch and release?
2. Maintain/Create a release branch from the live version and add the bugfix to that?

Option 1 seems to be what is advocated by continuous integration, but seems high risk.
Option 2 is what has been done historically, and is low risk.

Comment: this should be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It depends ! If you think your bugfix is envolving deep changes then you should create a branch on which you you work, otherwise (and normaly) bugfixes are not that risky, the assumption is that the one who is fixing the bug knows what is he doing, so it can be done on the head.

PS. making a branch will force you to merge later which can be really annoying if the head gets a lot of changes in while you are implementing the bugfix.

Comment: The concern is not so much the bugfix, but rather the other changes that have gone in since the build went live. (Option 1) So how do we do a minimal risk fix?

Comment: In my opinion Option1 is the easiest way, you have only to test the fixes, a 3rd Option would be to make a branch on which you make the bugfix, and merge everyday the changes from head into that branch so the difference between both would be miminla which will make the final merge easier.

Comment: regarding Option2, you may consider the reintegration option (if you are using SVN). take a look at http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2008/07/subversion-merg/

Comment: Actually we are using GIT, so creating a temp branch on the release version of the repo, and adding the fix into that is an option(Option 2). Option 1 is problematic in the instance where the release was done months ago. Making the fix in continuous integration branch means adding risk of all the subsequent changes that went in, and are not currently on the live build. How do other teams manage this risk? So far I have not heard a satisfactory answer, so more feedback would be great.